# Apache Camel - Send to seda queue only if not currently working with a message?

Tags: apache-camel

Would it be possible to achieve the following:

- Sending msg a to Incoming, route A handles the message
- Sending msg b to Incoming, route B handles the message
- Sending msg a to Incoming, but since routeA is still handling the first message, this one starts blocking the incoming route to handle more messages.

Once route A is finished, the incoming router sends the third message to A and keeps getting messages from the incoming queue

```
from(incomingQueue)
    .routeId("Incoming")
    .choice()
    .when(header("key").isEqualTo("a"))
    .to("seda:A")
    .when(header("key").isEqualTo("b"))
    .to("seda:B")
;
from("seda:A")
    .routeId("A")
    .process(processor);
from("seda:B")
    .routeId("B")
    .process(processor);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) will ACK back to the producer immediately and queue requests internally in routes A/B....

To block the producer in your incomingQueue route from sending to A/B routes until they have completed, then make your A/B routes [DIRECT](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) (synchronous).

note - I think this is what you asked for, but keep in mind that the A msgs/route would also block all B messages as well using this setup...

another option is to use something like [ActiveMQ message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html), which allows single-threaded processing of related messages while allowing for parallel processing of other groups, etc...

Comment: As you said, Direct would block all B messages too. I guess maybe just set a flag or something would work...